# Pattern matching

Tags: pattern-matching

This is a very simple question I hope you can help me with. I am experimenting with pattern matching. I want to write a pattern for a difference between two symbols, `a-b`, that recognises cases like `{a-2,a-2b,f[x]-g[x]}` as special cases while rejecting cases like `{a,a+b,a+2b,f[x]+g[x]}`.

So I started experimenting

Now when I write

```
MatchQ[a + 2b, a_ + b_]
```

It returns `True`

When I write

```
MatchQ[a - 2b, a_ - b_]
```

It returns `False`, which surprises me given the first code snippet returns `True`.

I imagined my question could be solved by:

```
mypattern = a_ - _Integer. b_.
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check their `FullForm`s :)

Comment: Oh @rm-rf, just noticed your comment after posting answer; again...

Answer (score 3):

Use `FullForm` to find the reason!

```
FullForm[a_ - b_]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

whereas,

```
FullForm[a - 2 b]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Note how `-2` is absorbed into `Plus`. *Mathematica* does not have a built-in "-" and therefore translates that into something using `Plus`. One needs to be aware of this when dealing with patterns involving polynomials.

Lot more details in this [introductory guide](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29219/1215) prepared by the community.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys - very helpful. I solved the original question now:

```
mylist = {a - 2, a - 2 b, f[x] - g[x], a, a + b, a + 2 b, f[x] + g[x]}
mypattern = a_ + _. b_ /; b < 0
MatchQ[#, mypattern] & /@ mylist
```

Comment: Good! Note that as said in the guide "/" is also not a built-in. You may also want to explore commutativity and associativity, `Orderless` and `Flat` properties in _Mathematica_ terms; and `OneIdentity`, which is _Mathematica_ 's way to say that `Plus[x]` is just `x`, kind of saying that `Plus` has an identity element without mentioning it. See [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html)